# Method returns before items are added to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to  populate an `ArrayList` with values from a **Node** server request, but the list returns too early before the items get added.

This is how I am going about it so far:

```
List<String> entityList;

public RevReadAllFromServer() {
    entityList = new ArrayList<>();
}

private synchronized void doWork() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                JSONObject json = null;
                try {
                    json = new JSONObject(response);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JSONArray jArr = null;
                try {
                    jArr = json.getJSONArray("filter");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject e;
                    try {
                        e = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.v("MyApp", ">>>> User Name : " + e.getString("user_name"));
                        entityList.add(e.getString("user_name"));
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.v("MyApp", "That didn't work!");
            }
        });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

public List<String> revReadAllFromServer() {
    Thread tUI = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doWork();
        }
    });

    tUI.start();
    try {
        tUI.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.v("MyApp", ">>> List Size : " + entityList.size());

    return entityList;
}
```

The output:

```
2018-11-13 23:56:26.143 24807-28639/rev.ca.my_init_application V/MyApp: >>> List Size : 0
2018-11-13 23:56:26.400 24807-24807/rev.ca.my_init_application V/MyApp: >>>> User Name :  cool_guy_101_2018
```

As you can see, `>>> List Size : 0` outputs before `>>>> ALL REMOTE_REV_ENTITY_GUID >>>  : 1`. The list does not get populated, and returns before items get added into it.

How can I get it to work?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Why are you making your request asynchronously if you expect a synchronous response?

Comment: Coding error: `catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` --- Catching an exception and continuing as-if nothing went wrong is bad, really, really bad. E.g. if `new JSONObject(response)` throws JSONException, the code leaves `json = null`, which means that `json.getJSONArray("filter")` will throw **NullPointerException**. --- *"How can I get it to work?"* Stop catching exceptions early. Only catch exception for entire method of `onResponse` and **log the exception**, so you can see ***why*** the code failed.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `queue.add` is not a blocking method. It just queues your request and have it serviced when the service thread is getting executed.

you can use `RequestFuture` and call the blocking `get` method for getting the response before the thread gets terminated.

By the way I don't know why you have a thread if you are calling `join` immediately after creating the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is asynchronous, the list will be populated once the response is ready. And from there you can then use its data in every thing else you want.

That's logically interpreted this way: **DO --> REGISTER_TASK[ ON TASK FINISHED: DO...] --> RETURN**

`revReadAllFromServer()` will return the list just after starting the thread, this will not wait for the registered new task to complete but it will return after completing it's own task. If then you want to use the result of the registered task so you have to listen to its completion and add your instructions inside implemented methods.